# jQuery toggle('blind') wierd behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, toggle, margin

I have tried to make a sliding zone that is center horizontally on my screen with margin:auto; as you can see with this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7emdxof/). I'm using jQuery-UI toggle('blind') function to do this.

Be sure to make the result zone large enough so the part with the checkbox is centered and press **Button 2**.

If you are using Firefox, you should see that the box moves to the left of the result area while sliding.

If you are using Chrome... Well, I don't know what will be the result as I can't test this code on this browser.

If you are using IE, you should see that the box stay in the middle of the result area.

My HTML structure is fairly simple and looks like this :

```
<body>
    <div id="Wrapper"> 
        <div id="Menu">
            <ul id="MenuItems">
                <li><a href="#">Button 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="Button2">Button 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Button3</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
        <div  id="HideNSeek">
            <form>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input id="chk1" type="checkbox" name="check" value="value1">
                    <label for="chk1">Label 1</label>
                    <br>
                    <input id="chk2" type="checkbox" name="check" value="value2">
                    <label for="chk2">Label 2</label>
                </div>
            </form>             
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the JS is as simple as this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Button2").click(function(){
    $("#HideNSeek").toggle('blind');    
  });
});
```

I can't understand why the code do not behave the same way on both browser.

Is it a jQuery issue because the margin:auto; is not well supported ?

Is it a Firefox rendering issue ?

Comment: `toggle()` isn't a `jquery ui` method, but a `jquery` method.

Comment: But if you want to use toggle('blind');, you have to use jQueryUI, nope ?<br /> At least, this is how I understood it. And this does not explain why I get this weird behavior.

Comment: You were saying *"I'm using jQuery-UI toggle() function"*. I just corrected that... NVM. Yes, it doesn't explain the behaviour, which is why it's not an answer but a comment.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry. Fixed that. :)